# Donde instala eclipse el servidor web logic en linux?

Tags: linux, eclipse, weblogic

Buen día comunidad, he estado aprendiendo Java web y he tenido problemas con el servidor WebLogic, ya que instale el weblogic con el marketplace de eclipse. 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero ahorra tengo que agregarlo en el "new server" y no encuentro donde estará el home del servidor.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy usando la ultima version de **GNU/Linux lubuntu** y ya busque en mi carpeta home y parece no estar por ningún lado el servidor. 
Alguien podría ayudarme y decirme en donde es que eclipse instala el weblogic ?

Answer (score 2):

## Inicio de un servidor de administración del servidor WebLogic

Para iniciar sesión en el servidor de administración del servidor `WebLogic`

Para un sistema operativo ***Windows***, inicie el servidor de administración con:
`% DOMAIN_HOME% \ startWebLogic.cmd.`

Para un sistema operativo ***Linux***, inicie el servidor de administración con: `% DOMAIN_HOME% / startWebLogic.sh.`

Si el puerto ***SSL*** está configurado para el servidor de administración del servidor ***WebLogic***, en el navegador, vaya a la URL predeterminada `https://localhost:7002/console`. De lo contrario, en el navegador, vaya a la URL predeterminada `http://localhost:7001/console`.

Use sus credenciales administrativas para iniciar sesión en el servidor.